Google Ads Not Tracking Purchases/Sales Despite Having Them – Need Help with Conversion Tracking!
I’m running a Google Ads campaign, but I’m facing an issue with conversion tracking. Despite having sales and purchases coming through on my website, Google Ads isn’t showing any conversions. I’ve tried multiple methods to fix it, but nothing seems to work. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Verified the Google Ads Conversion Tracking Code: I’ve installed the tracking pixel (global site tag) on my website and checked if it’s firing correctly.
Used Google Tag Assistant: I’ve tested the tag with Google Tag Assistant, and it seems to be installed properly, but still no conversions are being recorded.
Set Up the Correct Conversion Actions: I’ve created the right conversion actions for "Purchases" on my Google Ads account, but they’re not being triggered.
Google Analytics Integration: I’ve linked Google Analytics with Google Ads and made sure that goal tracking is set up, but still no conversion data is coming through.

I’ve checked everything multiple times, but I still can’t get the purchases/sales to show up in my Google Ads account. Does anyone have suggestions on what I might be missing or any tips on troubleshooting this?

Are you sure the orders are coming via your ads, and not organic search (or somewhere else)?  Are you looking under Goals for this data, and are both GA4 Conversions and Google Tag conversions not showing?

Yes I already check it but doesn't show any thing and the tag of purchase doesn't firing
